# Issued ShapeRenderer beahavior on android

Tags: android, user-interface, libgdx, rendering, z-index

I'm using ShapeRenderer to draw some kind of circular indicator under a mask texture. Everything works perfectly and as expected on Desktop but when running the same code on android, the shape rendering is always on top. Another strange difference is that all shape rendering function calls seems inverted such the first shape is drawn on top.
I've reproduced the problem on a june 2020 libgdx nightly build and with the 20/09/2020 nightly build.

Here is the code :

```java
myConstructor(){
   sr = new ShapeRenderer();
   sr.scale(1 + 1.1f * GUI.ZOOM_RATIO, 1 + 1.1f * GUI.ZOOM_RATIO, 0f);
}

draw(Batch g,float arg){
   g.end(); // I have some batch rendering before
   sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
   sr.setColor(Color.CYAN);
   sr.circle(indX, indY, indicatorW + GUI.fit2Density(2));
   sr.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
   sr.arc(indX, indY, indicatorW, 0f, degrees);
   sr.end();
   g.begin();
   g.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
   g.draw(coolDownIndic, indX - coolDownIndic.getWidth() / 2 - GUI.fit2Density(2),
                            indY - coolDownIndic.getHeight() / 2);
}
```

On Desktop I see the texture rendred over the arc and the arc over the circle. This order is exactly inverted on android, you can see the expected behavior here [Desktop rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25ntD.png) and the incorrect behavior here [Android rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv9AN.png) ( the purple cloud on top is a particle emitter effect not linked to the issue).

I guess this is a bug, note that I'm using the scale method on the ShapeRenderer, not sure if it can be related.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need to set a projection matrix on the shape renderer? Anyway, try setting `  Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true); Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);` before calling `begin()` in case you've changed these settings elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Projection matrix is not needed but you was right about the gl20 properties which solve the issue. No bug here, I've got a post processing 3D rendering filter not enabled on android that seems to explain the different behavior.